# I have forgotten my password. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: password, encryption

Preface: my question **is not** the typical "I have forgotten my password" question.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04

I have forgotten the password to both my administrative account and for hard drive encryption. That being said, the machine in question is currently on and logged into a non-administrative account (i.e. I'm using it right now to type this.)

I realize that if I turn the machine off, the encryption key is effectively wiped and there will be no chance to recover any information after that point. But is there anything that I could do now?

Is it possible to hot-swap an OS and by-pass Ubuntu's user permission restrictions? Is there any active vulnerabilities that will allow me to by-pass those restrictions and read the files?

EDIT: I should add that the goal at this point is just to recover the data I have stored in my main user account. Also, because I am idiot, I changed the permissions of the user home folder directories so they couldn't be read by others. So I can't just look into the home file of my account.

Comment: I highly doubt there is. If it would be known, it would be fixed quite immediately. And we would not discuss about this in askubuntu.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping that because I had physical access to the machine while logged into an account that it would change something. Thank you though

Comment: " But is there anything that I could do now?" yes - back up everything you can while you can and re-install the OS this time taking a careful note of all passwords keys.

Comment: @24601 I wish I could back up everything, but everything that I want exists in the home folder of the other user. Thanks though. Its looking like I will just have to accept defeat

Comment: Store the pwd in a passwordsafe next time (and store that safe somewhere off line with an easier to remember password) Brute force might be an option but you would need to install tools on that system ... needs admin pwd. So you could unattach the disk, put in into another system and hack away from there... but you will not be able to boot it anymore if you can not unlock it. By the way: you do not have a backup? Or a backup tool active? That would be my 1st to set up for a system like this

Comment: can you use the sudo command such as **sudo su -**